# How to force manual reconnect in DD-WRT PPPoE connection mode?

Tags: dd-wrt, pppoe

I've recently purchased a WRT54Gl router, and installed a DD-WRT (version micro) on it. The router is set in the PPPoE mode, which is connected via wire to the DSL modem.

In order to change my external IP, I need to reset either the modem or the router so the new connection is made with new IP.

Is there a way to use webGUI from DD-WRT, or maybe via `telnet`: to tell it to redial the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this line via telnet

`killall -HUP pppd`

Answer (score 1):

You can also enter it under the `Administration > Commands` menu and select `Run Commands`